# Java version for Chronicle product

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-bytes

Chronicle product support Java 8 (openjdk8) or 11 (openjdk11)?
I see this https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chronicle/info mentions Java 8, but this was updated long back.

Comment: That was pretty simple: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/issues/604

Comment: Also on https://chronicle.software/chronicle-support-java-17/: "Note that we currently support all widely used LTS variants of Java: 8, 11 & 17."

Answer (score 0):

In terms of roadmap, you can see here https://github.com/OpenHFT/OpenHFT/blob/ea/docs/Version-Support.adoc

Java 8, 11, and 17 are supported for the current version.